# Trying to close and open LibreOffice Impress using python code

Tags: python, openoffice.org

Using raspberry pi running raspian. I want to open a *.odp when a trigger happens, then when another trigger happens, close the file and then open a different *.odp file. The issue: once LibreOffice Impress opens, it seems no longer available for receiving commands through terminal. The commands do seem to work only after we close LibreOffice Impress manually.

We have successfully sent both through terminal directly and via our python script to open a particular *.odp file. However, we cannot seem to close the presentation so that we can open another.

Here is a snippet of code. The rf codes are received from a remote control...

```
cmd_openShowOn = "sudo libreoffice --nologo --show /home/pi/Documents/memorable.odp"
cmd_openShowOff = "sudo libreoffice --nologo --show /home/pi/Documents/forgettable.odp"
cmd_kill = "pkill soffice.bin"

if rfdevice.rx_code_timestamp != timestamp:
    timestamp = rfdevice.rx_code_timestamp
    logging.info(str(rfdevice.rx_code) +
                 " [pulselength " + str(rfdevice.rx_pulselength) +
                 ", protocol " + str(rfdevice.rx_proto) + "]")
    if str(rfdevice.rx_code) == "87347": # receives code to trigger closing anything that might be open and opening slide show for 'memorable.odp'
        print ("Laser On")
        os.system(cmd_kill)
        os.system(cmd_openShowOn)

    if str(rfdevice.rx_code) == "87356": # receives code to trigger closing anything that might be open and opening slide show for 'forgettable.odp'
        print("Laser Off")
        os.system(cmd_kill)            
        os.system(cmd_openShowOff)
time.sleep(1)
```

Any subsequent response from LibreOffice Impress are ignored until we manually kill LibreOffice Impress.

Comment: Various ideas are given at https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/11039/how-do-you-close-libreoffice-calc-from-a-macro/.  Note especially the mention of `d.terminate()` in the answer by @sup.